# Game of War: Can I have more than one research queue with more than one academy?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

Can I build a second academy and thus have a second research queue in GoWFA?

I doubt it, because I have more than one barracks and only 1 training queue, etc. Before I tear down a building to experiment ..... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only have 1 academy.

As of 2017, there is a package in the shop that has a "permanent 2nd research queue." You can use that to have 2 things researching at the same time. The package is expensive though. It costs $100.

You can only have 1 training queue though. However, for the same price in a package, you can get a "permanent 2nd building queue", that will let you build 2 buildings at the same time.

The packages containing these items are hard to find, look for a package that has them. Good luck!